# `require': cannot load such file -- oauth

Tags: ruby, emacs, osx-yosemite

I was happily using Emacs's  [evernote-mode](https://github.com/pymander/evernote-mode) until stupidly removed OS X system ruby (I'm on Yosemite). Then I tried installing one via RVM (first tried 2.0 then 1.9), got all necessary gems, yet thing is still broken. Throws this message:

```
 $HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- oauth (LoadError)
from $HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from $HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/enclient.rb:40:in `<main>'
```

Please help me to fix that

**upd**: I don't see the point of reinstalling system ruby (as people suggested) and then having it conflicting with those that I want to use via RVM. Ruby developers advise to use RVM. I symlinked my default Ruby to /usr/bin/ruby.
I seems that specific script uses something I don't have. I remember having hard time figuring out all dependencies and gems and installing them the first time I used that script and after hours of investigating it finally worked. But this time I got stuck.

I tried to run the script outside of Emacs and it runs with no errors (maybe that's not enough to find what's broken)

I tried to run irb and require modules one by one. It says => true until reaches `require 'oauth/consumer'`. I guess that's what's missing maybe? I run `gem install oauth_consumer`. It installed few gems, and now says => true for oauth/consumer in irb, the script though still doesn't work

Comment: which version of ruby did you install with rvm? i presume not 1.9.1

Comment: `gem install oauth`?

Comment: It's real important that you pay really close attention when doing system administration. Removing Apple's Ruby just broke some of their apps that you might not use and could have broken apps you installed if they use the system Ruby. You can't arbitrarily replace it as their installation isn't in a standard place so a normal install won't really fix the problem. I think you're going to need to reinstall your OS, or at least the language subsets.

Comment: See "[Is it possible to reinstall/fix Mac OS X's system ruby without doing a complete OS reinstall?](http://superuser.com/questions/171433/is-it-possible-to-reinstall-fix-mac-os-xs-system-ruby-without-doing-a-complete/175858)" for information about restoring the System Ruby from your OS disks.

Answer (score 0):

i removed systems ruby once. i just had to go to the trash and put back everything i deleted and it worked for me. don't know how you "removed" your system ruby. besides, if you installed one with RVM then you have to tell RVM to choose and use/set a default ruby. because RVM won't install ruby 1.9.1 (rather a higher version which i think you did). So you have to set to that version.

Like this:

`$ rvm --default use 2.1.5`

don't forget to install oauth as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: I thought evernote-mode not working with the latest version, that's why I tried switching to 1.9.3

Comment: yup. as I said seems all necessary gems are installed

Comment: Most people working at the OS level don't use the Finder, so their changes won't be in the trash.